# Union type without polluting auto complete in TypeScript intellisense

Tags: typescript, intellisense

Consider the following TypeScript code:

```js
class InputWrapper<T> {
    public getValue(): T {
        // implementation details would go here
        return {} as T;
    }
}

class Foo<T> {
    public assign(input: T | InputWrapper<T>) {
        return input;
    }
}

const fooInstance = new Foo<{someProp: string}>();

fooInstance.assign({someProp: 'hello'});
fooInstance.assign(new InputWrapper<{someProp: string}>());
fooInstance.assign({});
```

At the final `fooInstance.assign({})` line, I would like the autocomplete for `assign`'s input to exclude `InputWrapper`'s properties, requiring instead either a full constructed instance of InputWrapper (`new InputWrapper()`) *or* the allowed input type object (`{someProp: string}`), not both at once.

Currently this is how the autocomplete looks (I don't want `getValue` to show up): [image: current undesired autocomplete behavior]

In a actual production code, `InputWrapper` may have *dozens* of properties. Thus, I'd like to exclude them all from auto-complete here as they completely obscure the simpler `{someProp: string}` type.

Comment: Added a `new InputWrapper` example to the code snippet to make it more clear that it still needs to be accepted as an input to `assign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it! By making the `assign` method generic, we can restrict the inputs more tightly:

```js
class Foo<T> {
    public assign<U>(input: U extends InputWrapper<T> ? U : T) {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Now auto complete only suggests completions for `T` (in this case `{someProp: string}`) but still allows a constructed instance of `InputWrapper`:

[image: fixed auto completion]

Full example:

```js
class InputWrapper<T> {
    public getValue(): T {
        // implementation details would go here
        return {} as T;
    }
}

class Foo<T> {
    public assign<U>(input: U extends InputWrapper<T> ? U : T) {
        return input;
    }
}

const fooInstance = new Foo<{someProp: string}>();

fooInstance.assign({someProp: 'hello'});
fooInstance.assign(new InputWrapper<{someProp: string}>());
fooInstance.assign({});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it via declaring type that excludes InputWrapper like

```js
class InputWrapper<T> {
  public getValue(): T {
    // implementation details would go here
    return {} as T;
  }
}

type ExcludeInputWrapper<T, U> = U extends InputWrapper<T> ? U : T;


class Foo<T> {
  public assign<U>(input: ExcludeInputWrapper<T, U>) {
    return input;
  }
}

const fooInstance = new Foo<{ someProp: string }>();

fooInstance.assign({ someProp: 'hello' });
fooInstance.assign(new InputWrapper<{ someProp: string }>()); // Valid input
fooInstance.assign({}); // would not propose methods from Input wrapper now
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work :( now an instance of `InputWrapper` cannot be an input to the `assign` method.

Comment: @derpedy-doo oops. Corrected type, try `type ExcludeInputWrapper<T> = T extends InputWrapper<infer U> ? U : T | InputWrapper<T>;
`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, however that puts us back at `T | InputWrapper<T>` which still provides autocomplete with properties from `InputWrapper`

Comment: @derpedy-doo tricky thing. Played with it for 30 minutes and didn't find anything better your proposal like declaring type `type ExcludeInputWrapper<T, U> = U extends InputWrapper<T> ? U : T;
`
Nice :)